# Explanation of exponent integration

Tags: calculus, integration

It has been over $5$ years since I have done integration. After doing some research I understood basic rules of integrating exponents, such as dividing by the power.

However, I am unable to understand

1) Where the "$1$" came from in the photo attached in the final solution.

Also, I assume "$n$" came from substituting "$t$" for "$n$". But could someone

2) Explain how "$t=0$" affects the solution?

photo of problem:

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two doubts are actually linked.

\begin{align}
\int_0^n a_0 \exp(-(i-g)t) \, dt &a= a_0 \left[\frac{\exp(-(i-g)t)}{-(i-g)}\right]_\color{blue}0^n \\
&= a_0\left[\frac{\exp(-(i-g)n)}{-(i-g)} - \frac{\exp(-(i-g)\color{blue}0)}{-(i-g)} \right] \\
&=a_0\left[\frac{\exp(-(i-g)n)}{-(i-g)} - \frac{\color{red}1}{-(i-g)} \right] \\
&=a_0\left[\frac{1-\exp(-(i-g)n)}{(i-g)}\right]
\end{align}

Recall that $e^0=1$.